# Conky with gcalcli doesn't give proper calendar format in desktop

Tags: 14.04, conky

I installed `gcalcli` and `conky`, and have authenticated `gcalcli` to google as well. The output of the `gcalcli` command in conky is, however, completely useless-

[image]

Compared to the terminal output:

[image]

Here is my `.conkyrc` file-

```
alignment top_right
background no
border_width 0
cpu_avg_samples 2
default_color white
default_outline_color yellow
default_shade_color yellow
draw_borders yes
draw_graph_borders yes
draw_outline no
draw_shades no
use_xft yes
xftfont DejaVu Sans Mono:size=12
gap_x 5
gap_y 30
minimum_size 5 5
net_avg_samples 2
double_buffer no
out_to_console no
out_to_stderr no
extra_newline no
own_window yes
own_window_class Conky
own_window_type desktop
own_window_transparent no
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
stippled_borders 0
update_interval 5.0
uppercase no
use_spacer none
show_graph_scale no
show_graph_range no
text_buffer_size 64192

TEXT
${execi 300 gcalcli calw}
```

How do I get the proper calendar format in conky widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by getting a script off a site, that formats the conky output [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zjrielj6jk1jshi/gcal.sh?dl=0).
Here's the content of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

gcalcli --conky calw 4 |
    sed -e 's/(0\x71(B/-/g' \
        -e 's/(0\x78(B/|/g' \
        -e 's/(0\x6A(B/-/g' \
        -e 's/(0\x6B(B/|/g' \
        -e 's/(0\x6C(B/-/g' \
        -e 's/(0\x6D(B/|/g' \
        -e 's/(0\x6E(B/-/g' \
        -e 's/(0\x74(B/|/g' \
        -e 's/(0\x75(B/-/g' \
        -e 's/(0\x76(B/|/g' \
        -e 's/(0\x77(B/-/g' \
        -e 's/(0\x78(B/|/g' \
        -e 's/(0\x6A(B/-/g' \
        -e 's/(0\x6B(B/|/g' \
        -e 's/(0\x6C(B/-/g' \
        -e 's/(0\x6D(B/|/g' \
        -e 's/(0\x6E(B/-/g' \
        -e 's/(0\x74(B/|/g' \
        -e 's/(0\x75(B/-/g' \
        -e 's/(0\x76(B/|/g' \
        -e 's/(0\x77(B/-/g'
```

Just place it inside the `.config` folder of your home directory.

And here is my `.conkyrc` file:

```
alignment top_right
background true
border_width 0
cpu_avg_samples 2
default_color white
default_outline_color white
default_shade_color white
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders yes
draw_outline no
draw_shades no
use_xft yes
xftfont DejaVu Sans Mono:size=6
gap_x 0
gap_y 20
minimum_size 5 5
net_avg_samples 2
double_buffer yes
out_to_console no
out_to_stderr no
extra_newline no
own_window yes
own_window_class Conky
own_window_type override
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
stippled_borders 0
update_interval 300
uppercase no
use_spacer none
show_graph_scale no
show_graph_range no
text_buffer_size 16096
max_specials 2048
pad_percents 0


TEXT
${execpi 300 ~/.config/gcal.sh}
```

Place this `.conkyrc` file inside your Home (~/) folder.

This is how my desktop looks now :)

[image]

Here is my blog post about the complete process - [link](https://goelakash.wordpress.com/2016/02/06/adding-google-calendar-to-desktop-ubuntu-14-04-3/).

Comment: Nice, but this answer is worthless if those links go dead.

Comment: @muru How about now?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a python script converting the data to a proper conky format.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment because of lack of reputation but I just wanted to say that you can achieve almost the same result with the --nolineart option.

e.g.

```
gcalcli --monday --conky --nolineart calw 2
```